# Apache redirect to another domain all URLs, except for ones starting with substring

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, regex

Can anyone help me achieve a redirect in Apache from http://subdomain.example.com/ to http://example.com/ for all URLs, EXCEPT the ones starting with "files/"?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code below in `subdomain.example.com` virtual host section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that both subdomains have the same document root. Is there any way I could prevent infinite redirection for the example.com?

Comment: You can check `%{HTTP_HOST}`.